# Dimension of the Severi Variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves, moduli-spaces

Edit: In short, I know how to get a lower bound given that nodal curves are dense, and I know how to show nodal curves are dense given the lower bound, I can't find a reference that proves either fact independently.

---

Let $V_{d,g}$ be the Severi variety given by the closure of the curves of genus $g$ and degree $d$, as a subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^{\binom{d+2}{2}-1}$. It is known that the dimension of any component is $3d+g-1$.

I know a reference for the upper bound, but how do we show $\dim(V_{d,g})\geq 3d+g-1$?

(If we already know the curves with $\delta = \binom{d-1}{2}-g$ nodes is dense in $V_{d,g}$, then we could apply an incidence correspondence parameterizing plane curves with a choice of $\delta$ singular points, however, I think the proof that I can find of this fact uses $\dim(V_{d,g})=3d+g-1$, and I'd like to avoid circular reasoning. )

Comment: Each node is a codimension 1 condition in $\overline{M}_g$, so you can get the lower bound by Krull's Principal Ideal thm.

Comment: But how do you know there isn't a component of the Severi variety of lower dimension that consists entirely of triple points? This won't happen, but I can't find a proof of this that doesn't rely on the lower bound for the dimension. I think it's easy to see the closure of the locus with $\delta$ nodes is codimension at most $\delta$, but that isn't enough, are you doing something different?